# Drupal variables in region templates

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm doing my first totally custom Drupal 7 theme. I have the page.tpl.php file working fine and have header and footer regions working, until I move this:

```
<?php print render($page['main_menu']); ?>
```

into region--header.tpl.php - the menu is no longer generated - the html around the PHP is generated - nav etc. so I know drupal's reading the template file OK.

The same code works fine if it is in page.tpl.php

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main menu available as block. So you can just put him to this region. It's good practice.
Also don't forget to clear drupal/browser cache.

If you define custom variable in `preprocess_page()` or any other preprocess functions you shouldn't use render function, just use `print $main_menu` for example.

Also try check [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65616/how-to-include-a-custom-menu-in-page-tpl)